# File download problem in chrome using ir.actions.act_url

Tags: python, odoo-14

I have requirement to download uploaded binary files in one zip file. For this i have searched out and found like [Download from Attachments files in zip format odoo 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768964/download-from-attachments-files-in-zip-format-odoo-15)

I have followed these steps and used res_field to fetch data from ir.attachment model. I have successfully done the task.Its working on mozilla but not in chrome and other browsers.

```
<button name="download_vendor_attachments" type="object" class="fa fa-download"/>

    def download_vendor_attachments(self):
        return {"type": "ir.actions.act_url",
                "url": "/download_attachments?res_id={}".format(self.partner_id.id),
                }
```

and

````
import base64
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request

class DownloadZipFile(http.Controller):
    @http.route("/download_attachments/", type="http", auth="user", website=True, cors="*")
    def download_attachments_vendor_routes(self, **data):

        attachments_items = request.env["ir.attachment"].sudo().search(
            [("res_id", "=", data.get('res_id')),
             ('res_model', '=', 'res.partner'),
             ('res_field', 'in', ('file_siup', 'surat_dirjen'))])

        in_memory = BytesIO()
        zip_archive = ZipFile(in_memory, "w")

        for attachment in attachments_items:
            ext = '.' + attachment.mimetype.split('/')[1]
            if ext == '.vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
                ext = '.docx'
            zip_archive.writestr(f"{attachment.name}{ext}", base64.b64decode(attachment.datas))

        zip_archive.close()
        res = http.send_file(in_memory, filename="LegalDocuments.zip", as_attachment=True)
        return res
```
and xml as
```
               <page string="VENDOR LEGAL DOCUMENT" name="tender_legal_documents" id="tender_legal_documents">
                   <field name="legal_documents_ids">
                    <form create="false" edit="false" delete="false">
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="partner_id" readonly="1"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <group colspan="4" col="6">
                                <field name="nomor" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="salinan" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="surat" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                            </group>
                            <group colspan="4" col="6">
                                <field name="akta" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="pernyataan" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                                <field name="keterangan" attrs="{'readonly': True}"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </form>
                    <tree editable="bottom" create="false" open="false" delete="false" edit="false">
                        <field name="partner_id"/>
                        <field name="nomor"/>
                        <field name="salinan"/>
                        <field name="surat"/>
                        <field name="akta"/>
                        <field name="pernyataan"/>
                        <field name="keterangan"/>
                        <field name="download_btn" widget="html" />
                    </tree>
                   </field>
               </page>

```
Need guidance.
````

Answer (score 0):

You should use browser's native download feature instead of Odoo action.

`<a href="/download_attachments" download="Filename.zip">Download</a>`

In case you are not using Qweb Templates, and your need is to customize more server-side your link, use a computed field using `widget="html"`

```
download_btn = fields.Char(compute="_compute_download_btn")

def _compute_download_btn(self):
  for record in self:
    record.download_btn = "<a href='/download_attachments?res_id=%d' download='Filename.zip'>Download</a>" % (record.partner_id.id)
```

In your XML view:

```
<field name="download_btn" widget="html" />
```

Comment: i have implemented code file has been downloaded successfully  but when i click on download link a form also open.
Please guide how to avoid form open on download click and when i click on record then form should be open.

Comment: Actually i have to used this link on tree view with each record. When i click on link, a form appear as well

Comment: You mean an odoo form? Or a new blank page in your browser?

Comment: odoo form as i have tree and form view of One2many field

Comment: Ok, so i assume you're using `download_btn` field inside a column of a tree view.
In this case, you should prevent records from being opened. Best way is to mark `readonly` all tree view fields and set these attributes to your tree view:

`<tree editable="bottom" create="false" open="false" delete="false" edit="false">`

Comment: yes i am using field inside a column of a tree view. i have made changes as per you but still form opens.

Comment: You should share your code so we can further investigate

Comment: Code shared by edit question